# Dynamically create pydantic model for fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

How can I configure request parameters for an API endpoint using a JSON-based configuration?

For instance, I have a JSON configuration like this:

```
{
   "first_name": "string",
   "last_name": "string",
   "age": "integer"
}
```

I'm dynamically generating a Pydantic model class as follows:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class Record(BaseModel):
    pass

def generate_pydantic_record_model(config):
    for attribute_name, data_type in config['attributes'].items():

        if data_type == "string":
            setattr(Record, attribute_name, str)

        elif data_type == "date":
            setattr(Record, attribute_name, str)

            @validator(attribute_name, allow_reuse=True)
            def validate_date_format(cls, value, values, attribute_name=attribute_name, config=config):
                date_format = config['attributes'][attribute_name].get(
                    "format", "%d/%m/%y")
                if value is not None:
                    try:
                        datetime.strptime(value, date_format)
                    except ValueError:
                        raise ValueError(
                            f"Invalid date format for '{attribute_name}'. Date should be in the format {date_format}")
                return value

        elif data_type == "integer":
            setattr(Record, attribute_name, int)

generate_pydantic_record_model(validator_converter.data_config)
```

Issue is I'm not seeing the Record class in fastapi Swagger UI. Also I'm getting validation error